# Populate ComboBox control with data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am doing a c# WFA program. I want the comboBox to be able to display the car brand from the data grid view but I'm not sure how to do that.

See [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwIvy.png)

Comment: This question does not show any research or effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it from a database? Then you could try something like this.

```
string Sql = "select brand from [Car]";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"path_to_db");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (DR.Read())
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => ComboBox1.Items.Add(DR[0])));
        }
```